# Passing XML data as a class object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a publish method which takes class object as input. That class is created by converting XML into C# class.

Now, I am trying to test this publish menthod on my local machine but I do not have data as elements. All I have is huge XML data. How do I pass this XML data to publish method as class object?

Please help.

Publish Method

```
public SwsDefaultOut HechPublish(createupdatePerson_Output createUpdatePersonOutput)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallBackHechPublish, createUpdatePersonOutput);
        long transactionId = -1;

        if (createUpdatePersonOutput != null && !long.TryParse(createUpdatePersonOutput.HechPublishId, out transactionId))
            transactionId = -1;

        return new SwsDefaultOut { TransactionId = transactionId };
    }  



/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3190.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/mdm/customer")]
public partial class createupdatePerson_Output : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    
    private string hechPublishIdField;
    
    private string error_spcCodeField;
    
    private string error_spcMessageField;
    
    private string externalSystemIdField;
    
    private string object_spcIdField;
    
    private SCC_CONSTITUENT_IN_SYNC_DS sCC_CONSTITUENT_IN_SYNC_DSField;
    ......
}
```

Comment: You mean how to deserialize an XML string to a `createupdatePerson_Output` object? Use [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer)

Comment: I agree with Klaus.  It looks like your publish method is taking an instance of class data as input.  You need to initialize the class objects by parsing the xml string by using Xml Deserial method.  It is only a few lines of code.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your `HechPublish` method to accept a `string` instead of the type you're looking to deserialize to.

For example

```
public SwsDefaultOut HechPublish(string createUpdatePersonOutputXml)
```

I think updating the `HechPublish` method to something like you see below should work as long as the `createUpdatePersonOutputXml` argument is valid Xml.

```
public SwsDefaultOut HechPublish(string createUpdatePersonOutputXml)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(createupdatePerson_Output));
    createupdatePerson_Output createUpdatePersonOutput;

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(createUpdatePersonOutputXml))
    {
        createUpdatePersonOutput = (createupdatePerson_Output)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallBackHechPublish, createUpdatePersonOutput);
    long transactionId = -1;

    if (createUpdatePersonOutput != null && !long.TryParse(createUpdatePersonOutput.HechPublishId, out transactionId))
        transactionId = -1;

    return new SwsDefaultOut { TransactionId = transactionId };
}
```